# how to add and remove a style class on anchor tag

Tags: css, angularjs, html

I am struggling on adding and removing a style class on a anchor tag. I want to add a active class when I clicked on that tag and remove active from last active one. By default Home page would be active. I have tried many things but no success on that!

I have added few code but it is not working. Below is the code:

angularjs code:

```
$scope.isActive = false;
        $scope.getCSSClass = function () {
                return 'active';
            }

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <span class="whitelogo"><img src="styles/images/logo-small.png" alt="logo"></span>
    <div class='clearfix'></div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="closebtn" ng-click="closeNav()">&times;</a> 
    <a ng-link="['/Home/']" title="Home" class="active"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</a> 
    <a ng-link="['/TestForm/']" ng-class="getCSSClass()" title="Application Form"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i> test Form</a> 

</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have found the solution. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

On Angularjs file, I have added this code:

```
$scope.getStyleClass = function (path) {
            var cur_path = $location.path().substr(0, path.length);
            if (cur_path == path) {
                if ($location.path().substr(0).length > 1 && path.length == 1)
                    return "";
                else
                    return "active";
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }
```

And on Html side:

```
ng-class="getStyleClass('/TestForm')"
```